# Star not working in extjs requires

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I was under the impression that using '*' in require will allow you to import all classes in that package.

This does not work :

```
Ext.define('EM.app.myController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    requires: [
        'EM.app.controlUnit.searchModule.*'
    ],
```

However this does work :

```
Ext.define('EM.app.myController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    requires: [
        'EM.app.controlUnit.searchModule.SearchPanel'
    ],
```

This does not work as expected.

I am using SearchPanel as an xtype and a very obscure error is thrown pertaining to some substring on undefined on some rewrite objects in some parseNamespace method (that's a whole other story... 5 hours down the drain trying to figure that one out)

Is this maybe because I am using an old version of Extjs (4.1) ?

Comment: 1.4 or 4.1? I use 6.2 and it works from 5.2, always used

Comment: Ok now i understood

Comment: you should try requiring EM.app.controlUnit.serachModule , that should require all inside searchModule

Comment: you mean without the star

Comment: no that does not work. It also has no idea if searchModule is a file or directory if you do it like that.